# Grails g:select optionValue

Tags: grails, gsp

I having a grails element

```
<g:select name="name" from="${list}" optionKey='code' optionValue='name' ></g:select>
```

where the optionValue contains some HTML elements like this,

[image]

I want to show only the country name, already I tried using encodeAsHTML(), but no idea how to use. Please suggest.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

you can not do this with the out-of-box `g.select` tag. you need to iterate through your list manually:

```
<select name="someName">
  <option value="">- no select -</option>
  <g:each in="${list}" var="c">
    <option value="${c.code}">${c.name.replaceFirst( /<span class='countryName'>([\w\s]+)</span>/, '$1' )}</option>
  </g:each>
</select>
```

Comment: This is incorrect, using 'raw' allows you to pass through html unencoded. as per the answer by @user1690588

Comment: Your initial sentence is incorrect. You state it cannot be done using the g.select tag.  It can.

Comment: no. the initial sentence is just fine. You have to pre-process the input before you feed it to `select`, as the select can't escape it on it's own

Comment: Then we'll have to agree to disagree.  Your answer leads the reader to believe they cannot use the g.select period.   An no - you don't need to pre-process,  you can use the raw within the optionValue attribute, e.g  optionValue="${{raw(someVariable)}}"

Answer (score 1):

This is happening because of [XSS](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/security.html#xssPrevention). Instead of `encodeAsHTML` use `raw`. Try this:

```
<g:select name="name" from="${list.collect { raw(it) }}" optionKey='code' optionValue='name'/>
```